# How to pass a static class as an argument in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a base class called "Entity" which has a static method called "construct" that returns an Entity instance. I have several different subclasses of this class (for demonstration assume we have "Fruit" and "Vegetable" as subclasses). 
I would like to be able to do something along the following lines:

```
Entity a = someFunction(Fruit, textfile)
```

someFunction would then pass textfile to Fruit.construct and return the Entity generated.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) instead.
Pass the text file to the factory method that will use it to return the proper concrete instance of `Entity`

Comment: But what he describes **already is the factory pattern**. Do you mean that he can get away without passing the class object? How do you know this is possible?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik:I don't think so.I think he has a base class that knows how to read the text file and he wants to reuse that in the subclasses.He should **refactor** this into the factory pattern

Comment: This is the right answer, but do you think you could clarify a bit with an example?

Comment: @Tim:There are literally thousands of presentations of this pattern available.If you think that some specific point should be addressed, I could update my answer

Comment: That is why I was thinking an example could help. Personally, in this case I would think he should be passing in the factory to be invoked by `someFunction` but as you said there are many possibilities.

Answer (score 7):

You mean something like this:

```
public <T> T someFunction(Class<T> clazz, String textFile) throws Throwable {
 return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

The above code will use the no-arguments Constructor of the class (assuming there's one).

If your class needs to be instantiated with a specific constructor, you can do follow this example:

```
public <T> T someFunction(Class<T> clazz, String textFile) throws Throwable {
  // Here I am assuming the the clazz Class has a constructor that takes a String as argument.
  Constructor<T> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class});
  T obj = constructor.newInstance(textFile);
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass `Fruit.class` to the function and then use reflection on that class object to invoke the proper constructor. Note that this will couple your superclass quite tightly to its subclasses by demanding that constructor to exist.

Answer (score 2):

`Fruit` in your example is a type, and while `Fruit.eat()` might refer to a static method, `Fruit` is not a "static class".

There is a "class Object" which is actually an `Object` that *represents* the class.  Pass it instead.  To get to it, they syntax `Fruit.class` is used.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to implement an object-oriented design pattern, [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), using procedural code. Don't do it.

Instead, create an interface called `EntityConstructor`, which defines the method `construct()`. Make `Fruit` and `Vegetable` implement that interface. Then change `someFunction()` to take an instance of that interface.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a implementation :

```
public <T extends Entity> T someMethod(Class<T> entityClass, File file) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        T newEntity = entityClass.newInstance();
        // do something with file
        // ...
        return newEntity;
    }
```

You should look to

- introspection : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()
- generics : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are not inherited, per se, in that if your code has Entity.construct(...) it will not dynamically link that to the sub class.

The best way to accomplish what you are asking for is to use reflection to invoke the construct method on the Fruit class (or whatever class was passed into the someFunction() method.